# Print fast changing text on Android phone screen

Tags: android, android-sensors

In Android, I'd like to print fast changing text (>10 Hz) on the smartphone screen instead of into the log file. How should I change the following code?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { 
    System.out.println(event.values[0] );  
}
```

Comment: Um, call `setText()` on a `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a textview in your activity and in the method

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { 
    textView.append(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an external library. Lynx for example provides a screen with the input of the logcat, and it is very easy to configure.

https://github.com/pedrovgs/Lynx